# How to Edit Excel file from Jenkins UI?

Tags: java, excel, svn, jenkins

Consider the following scenario:

1. Scripts are present in Subversion repository.
2. Jobs are created in Jenkins for scripts.
3. The scripts work based on data present in an Excel sheet in the Subversion repository.
4. QA runs the build and it fails.
5. QA needs to edit the Excel document in the Subversion repository to try again with new Test Data.

In the above scenario, please let me know how can the QA be given option to edit the Excel document and upload it into the Subversion repository.

Comment: Does excel has REST api? Look like so: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ee556413%28v=office.14%29.aspx.  Your tags are not appropriate.  Also there is no apparent effort from your side. Question should be closed (in the current form)

Comment: Give QA the permission to edit this particular file in SVN. or remove the file from SVN, keep it in some location that QA can modify and make the scripts to fetch the file from that location, it can be even your workspace.

Comment: When you post a question to a StackExchange site, please use the [Markdown](http://daringfireball.net/projects/markdown/) to format your questions and not HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several options:

1. Get QA access to SVN. Use TortoiseSVN to have them access SVN through Windows explorer (it integrates with the context menu)
2. Remove the file from SVN and upload the file every time you run the Jenkins job (File Parameter).
3. Find a new location for the excel file. Your QA people and Jenkins both need to have access to this location.

Comment: Option 1 will increment version number for each change to TestData, and hence may not be viable.

Comment: But Option 2 and 3 looks promising. I will try to implement anyone of those and post back the details.

Comment: Option 3 is working fine. Thank you for your valuable suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Is there a problem if QA has read-only access to your Subversion repository? I can imagine that you don't want them to edit anything in the repository besides these Excel files, but not to touch anything else. I can also understand if you don't want your developers editing this Excel spreadsheet because this is QA's file to maintain.

In this case, you can use  this [pre-commit hook](https://github.com/qazwart/SVN-Precommit-Kitchen-Sink-Hook) to say who is allowed to edit what files. It uses Perl and you need version 5.8.8 or higher (the latest is 5.18). This is already probably available on your Linux or Mac, and is easily installable on [Windows](http://strawberryperl.com) as a free open source program.

With this pre-commit hook, you create a control file to control access:

```
[file Only QA is not allowed to touch the QA Excel spreadsheets]
file = **/*.xls
access = read-only
users = @ALL

[file QA users may only edit the QA Excel spreadsheets in this repository]
file = **
access = read-only
users = @QA

[file QA users may only edit the QA Excel spreadsheets in this repository]
file = **/*.xls
access = read-write
users = @QA
```

Permissions go from top to bottom. So in this setup, users in the `@QA` group can't commit changes to anything but the Excel spreadsheets while everyone else is allowed to modify all files but those Excel spreadsheets.

Now, QA can use Subversion to modify these spreadsheet without being allowed to modify anything else in your repository, and as a bonus, no one else is allowed to touch these QA spreadsheets.

This way, the spreadsheets are in the version of the software that matches the scripts for that version. Otherwise, you will have to modify Jenkins to download these spreadsheets from another server before building, or make the downloading of the spreadsheets part of your build process. Neither is going to be very fun.

Comment: This looks a very high tech solution. But one problem this may cause is that, for every change in the TestData file the version number will get incremeted. This is not desirable as it may lead to huge number of versions.

Comment: If that's a concern, take the TestData file out of your Subversion repository. However, this shouldn't be a concern. Otherwise, you'll have to store the TestData file elsewhere, and it won't be versioned with the software, so you can't rerun the tests, or branch.

Comment: What you say seems to be correct. I will carry forward these comments to my team and make the decision. Thanks a lot.